# Build OpenGL application for both x86 and x64 architectures on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit

Tags: opengl, linker, ubuntu-12.04, glut, 32-bit

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 and I try to compile and link the same code for both x86 and x64 architectures. It is a simple 3D application based on **OpenGL**. In fact it is not even 3D at the moment:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void draw(void)
{
    // Background color
    glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Draw order
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50,25);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,250);
    glutCreateWindow("Green window");
    glutDisplayFunc(draw);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

So, what I need is only lGL and lglut, right now. I installed them through the freeglut3 package and I suppose only the 64-bit version is what I got. When I compile and link for the 64-bit version (with `-m64`) everything goes fine but when doing it with `-m32` I get these errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so while searching for GL 
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lGL 
/usr/bin/ld: warning: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so while searching for glut 
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lglut
```

Now, my question is: where and how do I **get the 32-bit version of GL and glut** and how do I **link them** when building the 32-bit binary, if that is possible?

**UPDATE:**
I installed the :i386 variant of freeglut but now I get these linking errors for both architectures:

```
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lglut
```

Comment: Also, I see that installing the i386 variant removes the amd64 one and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO) package options should make it. with the magic command:

```
dpkg --add-architecture <arch>
```

If still in trouble, the [**last solution**](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apds03.html.en) would be a small 32bit chroot with [debootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap)

```
/usr/sbin/debootstrap --arch i386 jessie \
     /mnt/yournewsmall32bitenv http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian
```